# jquery validation code isn't working proper

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

i cant get the issue in my code , every thing working proper but issue is that when user click or focus first time on textbox correct img show .. this is incorrect but i cant solved this problem when user typing then after completing wher user correct type then show otherwise not shown . can any one help me regarding this issue . my complete jquery and html or css code are available in this link pls check and solved my issue

[my code link](http://jsfiddle.net/gU3PU/4/)

i think error on this function but icant get the issue

```
$('#step1 #fName').focus(function(){

        if($('#step1 #fName').hasClass('error_Aplha')==true)
        {
            $('#step1 #fntick').removeClass('block');    
        }
        else {
            $('#step1 #fntick').addClass('block');
        }
    }).blur(function(){

        if($('#step1 #fName').hasClass('error_Aplha')==true)
        {
            $('#step1 .fname_error').fadeIn(100).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);
            $('#step1 #fntick').removeClass('block');    
        }
        else {
            $('#step1 .fname_error').removeClass('block');    
            $('#step1 #fntick').addClass('block');
        }

    });
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, that's a lot of code for a simple task. Change it so the checks are only done in the `.keyup()` and `.blur()` events of the `INPUT` elements.

Not 100% sure what the intended behaviour is, but this will probably get you going:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    var errorAlpha = function() {
        var reg = /^([A-Za-z]+)$/;
        var check = $(this).val();
        if (reg.test(check) == true && check.match(reg) != null) {
            // VALID
            $(this).removeClass('error_Aplha');
            $(this).next('img').addClass('block');
            $(this).prevAll('span.tooltip2').stop(true).delay(500).fadeOut(400);
        } else {
            // INVALID
            $(this).addClass('error_Aplha');
            $(this).next('img').removeClass('block');
            $(this).prevAll('span.tooltip2').fadeIn(500).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);
        }
    };

    $('#step1 #fName, #step1 #lName').on('keyup blur', errorAlpha);

});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gU3PU/6/